No extensions or any other important things in Joomla 4.4.3 System Dashboard

I really need to get extensions, so maybe I could use code & add google maps to my Joomla website. Also if I add google maps "iframe" link, it just disappears when I save my project.
I dont know, is it Joomla version problem or I just do not have access to extensions. I did not create this project, so I am not superuser, I am just an admin.

Regarding iframes (extending Irata's answer), you need to edit the editor plugin - assuming you use TinyMCE - goto Manage/Plugins search tiny and change the settings if you have access, find Prohibited Elements and remove iframes.

In a standard Joomla installation the Administrator user group doesn't have permission to use the Installer or a number of other menu items only available to the Super Users group.
You could ask the Super User to grant Administrator permission to the Installer via the Global Configuration setting as shown in the following image.

If there is no Super User available and you are responsible for the site you should take steps to become a Super User.
You other question(you should only ask one question per post on Joomla Stack Exchange) relates to the the settings you have in the Text Filters for your site or 3rd Party Editor that is removing HTML code that is deemed not allowed and are removed when the article or content is saved.

